# Can we have non-proxy POCO's and POCO proxies in the same ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

Can I have a POCO that I don't want proxy to be generated for (so I don't set its properties `virtual`) and another POCO for whom I want a proxy to be generated (properties `virtual`) managed by the same `ObjectContext` against the same EDM in a single project?

If I set the `ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled` to `true` and have one of the POCO's only have it properties as `virtual`, will the Entity Framework create a proxy only for one and leave the other untouched even if I used `CreateObject<T>` on both?

Comment: good question, why don't you create a test app and find out?

Comment: Hi, sorry I did that eventually and found out that it was possible. I was trying to save some time to get an answer from someone who had already tried it earlier. After all, that's what asking for help is about. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go out on a limb here and say no, not based on anything other than how most mocking frameworks create dynamic proxies. At runtime the DataContext will create a proxy class inherited from your POCO. If nothing is virtual then it will provide no data support. I suspect it will notify you of this with an exception, but am not sure.

Why would you want EF to manage a simple class? There is nothing to manage. Sounds like you are trying to use EF as a stock standard factory class. Perhaps you could provide some context in the question?